# IOS/Core Data: How to fetch attribute from other entity through relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

I have a master detail controller with core data that fetches objects from one entity, i.e. Authors, and then lets you look at one of those objects in detail,i.e. one author.

The author object has a one to many relationship with a second entity, Books. For each author, I would like to display a clickable list of their books.

My first question is after displaying the author page, how would I fetch a list of the books.

Eventually, I would like to display the list in a label or button as clickable text perhaps using NSAttributed Text but for now would be happy to just retrieve the list of books.

The authors have a relationship to books, entitled, *book*, that is one to many and the books have a reciprocal relationship to authors, entitled *author*, that is one to one.

I import books.h (data file) into the authorsVC.h and authorsDetail.h controllers.

The authors.h file has a property as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Books *authorBook;
```

The following code does not throw an exception but logs out null.

```
 NSLog(@"books %@", _authorBook.bookname); //logs as null even when there are books for the author.
```

This code throws the exception shown:

```
NSLog(@"books %@", _author.book.bookname);

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet bookname]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Did you set the relationship before saving the context while creating the entity?

Comment: The **many** side of a one-to-many relationship in Core Data is always represented by an `NSSet` object. This is also indicated in the exception error message.

Comment: where do I use NSSet?  bookname is just the attribute name in the books entity.

Comment: You're talking about a relationship, not an attribute

Comment: the name of the relationship is book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did the trick.  Similar to Tom's whom I am not allowed to upvote given my rating but with a few adjustments as it would not accept the dot notation.  The valueForKey is for an array.

```
NSSet *books = _book.author;
   NSArray *booksarr = [[files valueForKey:@"author"] allObjects];
   NSString *bookstr = [booksarr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Once in a string, you can display it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To-many relationships in Core Data are realized as `NSSet` instances. In your case since `Author` -> `Book` is a to-many relationship, `_author.book` is an `NSSet` of `Book` instances-- which is the collection of books. `Book` may have an attribute called `bookName` but `NSSet` does not.

If you just want the book names, you'd use

```
_author.book.valueForKey[@"bookName"]
```

That will ask each `Book` in the set for its `bookName` and return a new set of just the book names.

Comment: Am getting error "Property 'valueForKey' not found on object of type Books* "

Comment: does this go in a for loop? Tried  NSSet *books =_author.book; NSSet *bookNames  = [books valueForKey:@"bookName"]; for (NSManagedObject *bookName in bookNames) {
        NSLog(@"book name is: %@", bookName);
    }; However the variable bookNames is empty and the for loop does not execute.  There is definitely a book name in the books entity.

Comment: Have gotten code to work with [_author.book valueForKey[@"bookName"];  For some reason dot notation does not work.  When I assign it to an NSString, however, it compiles but then checking class it is actually __NSSetI. Thus I cannot manipulate it as a string.  Does this make any sense?